# Exception caught by gesture( gesture )

Tags: flutter, dart

main.dart

this is my main.dart which contains only limited code and also limited Text fields. When I try to pass these values form main to second page the values are not get forwarded nor there's no error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pharmacy/Welcome.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController _name = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _email = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _phone = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _name,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Name',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _email,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Email',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _phone,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Phone',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Welcome(
                        name: _name.text,
                        email: _email.text,
                        phone: _phone.text),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Text('SEND'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Welcom.dart

this is my receiving page area , the values should display in this page but unfortunately the values are not get displayed. when i run the code i stuck with the main.dart page . with following error as showing : Exception caught by gesture

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pharmacy/Welcome.dart';


class Welcome extends StatelessWidget {
 final String name, email, phone;

 Welcome({ @required this.name,@required this.email, @required this.phone});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('Name = ${name}'),
          Text('Email = ${email}'),
          Text('Phone = ${phone}'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Already check on press function

Answer (score 0):

we used context passed by to build of MyApp.

The problem is, MyApp is actually a parent of MaterialApp. As it's the widget who instantiate MaterialApp! Therefore MyApp's BuildContext doesn't have a MaterialApp as parent!

To solve this problem, we need to use a different context.

In this situation, the easiest solution is to introduce a new widget as child of MaterialApp. And then use that widget's context to do the Navigator call.

There are a few ways to achieve this.
you can use Builder :

```
Builder( //wrap your button with Builder
                builder: (context) => Center(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Welcome(
                                name: _name.text,
                                email: _email.text,
                                phone: _phone.text),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text('SEND'),
                    ),
                 ),
              )
```

or You can extract home into a custom class :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome()
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController _name = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _email = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _phone = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _name,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Name',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _email,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Email',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: _phone,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Phone',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Welcome(
                        name: _name.text,
                        email: _email.text,
                        phone: _phone.text),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Text('SEND'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this solution is worked for you.